# Swift 3.1 equelent logic of this code

Tags: c, swift, swift3

I am Working on linear feedback shift register, I have to securely write the following logic, I have chosen swift as it is more secure compared to objective c
is it secured if I use the following C logic with as a C file itself? if not I am trying to write the following piece of code in swift

```
char * lfsr16_obfuscate( char *s, unsigned int length, unsigned int seed)
{
    unsigned int i, lsb;
    unsigned int lfsr = seed;

    for (i = 0; i < length*8; i++)          
    {
        lsb = lfsr & 1u;                
        lfsr >>= 1u;                    
        if (lsb == 1u)
        {
            lfsr ^= 0xB400u;
            s[i / 8] ^= 1 << (i % 8);   
        }
    }

    return s;
}
```

Following is swift equelent which I tried , But it is crashing as in the following screenshot, please help me out to write the above C code in swift 3.1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know about LFSR, but given the C code you present, I think the swift port might be like this:

```
func lfsr16_obfuscate(data: String, seed: Int) -> String {
    var scalars = Array(data.unicodeScalars).map { UInt8($0.value) }
    let len = data.characters.count
    var lsb: UInt
    var lfsr = UInt(seed)

    for i in (0..<len*8) {
        lsb = lfsr & 1
        lfsr >>= 1
        if 1 == lsb {
            lfsr ^= 0xB400
            scalars[i / 8] ^= UInt8(1 << (i % 8))
        }
    }

    return String(bytes: scalars, encoding: .ascii)!
}
```

Make sure that you won't process any String that contains characters other than ASCII characters with this function.